# Differenza tra 'di Russia' e 'della Russia'

Tags: word-usage, difference, prepositions

Ciao a tutti,
C'è qualche differenza tra 'di Russia' e 'della Russia'? Ho letto da qualche parte che con i paesi vicini all'Italia si usa 'di' e con quelli lontani si usa 'di + articolo'. È vero?
Grazie!

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5):

Non credo sia una regola generale.

Vi sono molti stati contemporanei il cui nome non è preceduto da alcun articolo. Queste sono [spesso di isole o città-stato](http://www.scudit.net/mdportapianazioni.htm).

> Assedio di Cipro
>
> Isole di Capo Verde
>
> Console di San Marino

Come vedi la distanza dall'Italia è irrilevante.

La netta sensazione è che più che una funzione della distanza ciò che veramente faccia la differenza sia l'entità geografica alla quale ci si sta riferendo.

Per indicare sovrani (anche contemporanei) di nazioni femminili si usa semplicemente "di"

> Re di Svezia
>
> Scià di Persia
>
> Zar di Russia
>
> Regina d'Inghilterra
>
> Negus d'Etiopia

La stessa cosa non succede per nazioni di genere maschile

> Re del Belgio
>
> Re del Botswana

Ci sono notevoli eccezioni. Si trovano casi di entità statali maschili in cui la tendenza sembra cambiata col tempo. Ad esempio, [sembra](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Re%20del%20Marocco%2C%20Re%20di%20Marocco&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRe%20del%20Marocco%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRe%20di%20Marocco%3B%2Cc0) che un tempo fosse più in voga "Re di Marocco" rispetto a "Re del Marocco".

È importante inoltre ricordare che il nome di molte di queste entità statali è spesso espresso tramite sineddoche. Quindi nella fattispecie

> Vladimir Putin, presidente della Federazione Russa -> Putin, presidente della Russia
>
> Angela Merkel, Cancelliera della Repubblica Federale di Germania-> Merkel, Cancelliera della Germania

Come vedi dunque, nessuna relazione alla distanza.

Comment: «Re d'Italia, non proprio un paese lontano»: Occhio, che l'OP dice infatti che “di” si usa per i paesi vicini e “del” per quelli lontani (comunque anch'io trovo curiosa questa regola basata sulla distanza).

Comment: @DaG giusto grazie!

Comment: Purtroppo, vista l’enorme complessità delle preposizioni in italiano, può capitare che si cerchi di individuare delle regole anche dove non ci sono… Sono come scialuppe di salvataggio in alto mare :-)

Comment: Grazie mille della spiegazione dettagliata!
Gli esempi con Putin e Merkel mi fanno pensare che l'articolo si usa in contesti piuttosto ufficiali. Non credo comunque che si tratta di sineddoche: l'articolo si usa anche con l'Ucraina (il presidente dell'Ucraina), ma Ucraina è l'unico ufficiale nome del paese (per es., nessuna Repubblica Ucraina).

Comment: Più che in contesti ufficiali sembra una caratteristica associata a "presidente".