# Are there rules about articles for nation names: La Francia, la Venezuela, la Cuba?

Tags: articles, gender

After having read this: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/articoli-e-preposizioni-davanti-ai-nomi-delle-isole/1300

which talks about articles and preposition for islands, I came to the conclusion that it is a matter that can not be ruled or analyzed. Then I searched, there, a post about nations, and found none. So I ask: are there some rules to categorize the different articles used for different nations? Why is "La Francia", but not "La Venezuela"; and why neither "La Cuba" or "Il Cuba" are used?

-- UPDATE on request --

I've found this page: https://www.italianoinonda.net/r052.shtml
where, under the section NAZIONI in the middle of the page, there is a short list of nations that *refuse* the article. Unluckily the page is no *sooo* trusty and the section is vague ("some names are not preceded by articles" ... "many country names are preceded by the article").

To summarize up, my questions are:

1) Where the gender of a nation name comes from.

2) Related - Why some name refuses the article (and this makes even more difficult to choose from "Cuba è stata"/"Cuba è stato".

3) The Most Important One, which encompasses the two above: how can I be sure to use the correct gender and article when referring to a nation? Is there a rule about that? Note: a rule could also be as simple as "*The following nations are females: ...; the following are male: ...; the following refuse the article: ...*"

Comment: Se ho inteso bene, ti riferisci principalmente a due fenomeni: articoli che sono in contrasto con il genere indicato dalla desinenza nominale o nazioni che rifiutano l'articolo in toto. Giusto?

Comment: @Nico bentornato! Sì, mi chiedo quale sia il motivo di un nome maschile o femminile, che determinerebbe l'articolo da usare, e che però contrasta con alcuni nomi che non voglio l'articolo. Cioè direi "Cuba è stata..." (quindi femminile), ma non "La Cuba...". Quindi sì, i casi sono almeno due.

Comment: Ipotesi riguardo a Cuba: non padroneggio lo spagnolo tanto da espormi, ma  non potrebbe trattarsi del fatto che l'italiano ha adottato l'articolo zero di cui penso faccia uso lo spagnolo in questo caso?

Comment: @Nico può essere, ma qui https://www.italianoinonda.net/r052.shtml riportano altre nazioni che con lo spagnolo non c'entrano. Proviamo ad aspettare i guru.

Comment: Da questo elenco si evince che, come scrivevi tu, si tratta di un fenomeno arbitrario che si sottrae a una categorizzazione stretta.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Potresti riformulare la domanda in modo dettagliato?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Ripensandoci, questa mi pare piuttosto una domanda di linguistica generale e non una domanda specifica per l'italiano. Resta comunque il fatto che nella sua versione originale la domanda era interessante e che nessuno l'abbia degnata di un tentativo di risposta pertinente. Il motivo penso ti sia più che chiaro.

Comment: Nice question. Sad that the comment section had to degenerate into a schoolboy fight. [Here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/differenza-tra-di-russia-e-della-russia) is a related question I tried to answer a few months back.

Comment: I've deleted further irrelevant comments. The appropriate place to discuss moderation activities is Meta, not the comments to a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look at nations, states or territories in Europe, the business seems quite easy:

- the majority of nations are feminine, with article;
- those that end in -o are masculine (*Portogallo, Lussemburgo, Belgio*), with article;
- the few that end in a consonant (*Galles, Liechtenstein*) are masculine, with article;
- an exception is to be made for the city-states (or considered such): *Andorra, Monaco, San Marino*; they don't want an article;
- nations that coincide (at least in their greater part) with an island follow the usage examined in the quoted thread (*l'Islanda, Malta, Cipro, le Fær Øer, la Groenlandia, Jersey, Guernsey*).

The nations, territories or states with complex names (*Regno Unito, Paesi Bassi, Città del Vaticano*) don't count, because they follow the main noun (*Regno, Paesi, Città*).

Going in other continents, the affair becomes more complicated. In Africa we find *la Nigeria*, but also *il Botswana*. *Angola* and *Uganda*, which take the article, are masculine or feminine?

In the *[Atlante Geopolitico Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uganda_res-54fe9058-18af-11e4-a818-00271042e8d9_%28Atlante-Geopolitico%29/)* I find, **in one and the same article**,

> In particolare, l’Uganda è stata direttamente coinvolta nelle vicende ruandesi degli anni Novanta: […]
>
> […]
>
> In generale, l’Uganda post-indipendenza è stato caratterizzato da una sequenza di conflitti tra il governo, il nord e il sud del paese, portatori di interessi contrapposti.

Not even the editors at Treccani seem to have clear ideas on the matter.

*Mauritius* is a small island, so it doesn't want the article, contrary to *le Maldive*, that are an archipelago. *La Réunion* (2,511 km<sup>2</sup>) is just a bit larger than *Mauritius* (1,864.8 km<sup>2</sup>), but it wants the article (like in French). It's very common to hear *le Mauritius*, but it is **one** island (with a few dependent islets).

In Central America we find *Costa Rica* that can take the article or not, depending on one's own preferences. *Cuba* is a rather big island (109,884 km<sup>2</sup>) and doesn't want the article; *la Giamaica* is much smaller (10,991 km<sup>2</sup>), but it wants the article.

In Southern America there's an amazing case: *il Venezuela* is masculine in Italian, but is feminine in Spanish. [Etimology is controversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuela#Etymology): the commonly accepted version is that the name was given by Vespucci who found a settlement vaguely resembling Venice because of stilt houses.

Conclusion: there is no “rule” and usage wins. Nations, states or territories that end in -o or in -e are masculine (no exception comes to my mind, excluding of course city-states) and want the article if they're not islands (*Cipro*). Those that end in a consonant are generally masculine, with article (there are a few exceptions such as *la Réunion*).

Islands are, in particular, a problem, but we already knew it.

---

Se guardiamo le nazioni, territori o stati europei, la questione sembra semplice:

- le nazioni sono in maggioranza femminili con articolo;
- quelle che finiscono in -o sono maschili (Portogallo, Lussemburgo, Belgio) con articolo;
- le poche che finiscono in consonante (Galles, Liechtenstein) sono maschili con articolo;
- fanno eccezione le città-stato (o considerate tali): Andorra, Monaco, San Marino che non vogliono l'articolo;
- le nazioni che coincidono (in gran parte) con un'isola seguono l'uso esaminato nella domanda citata (l'Islanda, Malta, Cipro, le Fær Øer, la Groenlandia, Jersey, Guernsey).

Le nazioni, territori o stati con nomi composti (Regno Unito, Paesi Bassi, Città del Vaticano) non contano, perché seguono il sostantivo principale (Regno, Paesi, Città).

Andando negli altri continenti, la faccenda diventa più complessa. In Africa troviamo “la Nigeria”, ma anche “il Botswana”. Angola e Uganda, che prendono l'articolo, sono maschili o femminili?

Nell'[Atlante Geopolitico Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uganda_res-54fe9058-18af-11e4-a818-00271042e8d9_%28Atlante-Geopolitico%29/) trovo, *nello stesso articolo*,

> In particolare, l’Uganda è stata direttamente coinvolta nelle vicende ruandesi degli anni Novanta: […]
>
> […]
>
> In generale, l’Uganda post-indipendenza è stato caratterizzato da una sequenza di conflitti tra il governo, il nord e il sud del paese, portatori di interessi contrapposti.

Nemmeno i redattori della Treccani sembrano avere le idee chiare al riguardo.

Mauritius è una piccola isola, quindi non vuole l'articolo, come invece le Maldive, che sono un arcipelago. La Réunion (2,511 km<sup>2</sup>) è poco più grande di Mauritius (1,864.8 km<sup>2</sup>), però vuole l'articolo (come in francese). È comune sentire “le Mauritius”, ma è un'isola sola (con alcuni isolotti dipendenti).

In America centrale troviamo “Costa Rica” che può avere l'articolo o no, dipende dalle preferenze. Cuba è un'isola piuttosto grande (109,884 km<sup>2</sup>) e non vuole l'articolo; la Giamaica è molto più piccola (10,991 km<sup>2</sup>), ma vuole l'articolo.

In Sudamerica c'è un caso bizzarro: il Venezuela in italiano è maschile, ma in spagnolo è femminile. [L'etimologia è controversa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuela#Etymology): la versione comunemente accettata è che il nome sia stato dato da Vespucci che trovò un insediamento vagamente somigliante a Venezia per via delle case su palafitte.

Conclusione: non c'è una “regola”. L'uso comanda. Le nazioni, stati o territori che finiscono in -o oppure in -e sono maschili (non mi vengono in mente eccezioni, a parte le città-stato, naturalmente) e vogliono l'articolo se non sono isole (Cipro). Quelli che finiscono in consonante sono generalmente maschili con articolo (poche eccezioni come la Réunion).

In particolare le isole sono un problema, ma lo si sapeva.

Comment: This answer is correct, except 'l'Uganda post-indipendenza' is masculine because it is like it said 'il periodo dell'Uganda durante la post-indipendenza'.

Comment: @RubenVerg I disagree. We don't say “L'Italia post-risorgimento è stato caratterizzato dal brigantaggio” , but “è stata caratterizzata”, because the subject is “Italia” which is feminine. Here “post-risorgimento” or in the quoted article “post-indipendenza” is an apposition to the subject.