Definite article with countries
In exercise 29 (2 and 8) of J. Germano, C. Schmitt, Italian Grammar (2nd Ed.), Schaum's Outlines Series, p.26, using di or della we have to fill the gaps of
(29.2) La capitale ______ Francia è Parigi.
(29.8) La sete _______ Cina è famosa.
The book gives della for both. Above this exercise the book gives examples such La capitale d' Italia è Roma or I vini di Francia sono deliziosi. It is obvious to me that the right answer is di for both. Do we have a book's mistake?

“using de or della”: Does your book say literally so? If so, there is a typo: the Italian preposition is di, non de. And sete is, more likely, seta (silk).

As for the rest of the question, are https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11657/are-there-rules-about-articles-for-nation-names-la-francia-la-venezuela-la-cu and https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/daustralia-oppure-dellaustralia useful?

@DaG de was my fault (as you can see below, I use di) and I am going to fix it.

@DaG the reference seems useful, but essentially I am asking how the examples are consistent with the answer. (I there is some ambiguity, the book would not answer like that.)

All of the sentences your book gives (la capitale d'Italia..., i vini di Francia..., la capitale della Francia..., la seta della Cina...) are correct. “La capitale dell'Italia” would be correct too (while “i vini di Francia” sounds a bit wooden; one would likely say “i vini francesi”). Of course, it's questionable that the book gives examples of one kind and exercises of another kind.
As regards when to use the article before a country's name, when it isn't needed, and when both possibilities are correct, I believe that previous Q&As already cover this, but of course ask if there are cases not covered there.

In conclusion di+country is equivalent to di+ definite article +country?!

No, not at all. Sorry if I wasn't clear: there are cases where you use the article before a country's name, others when it isn't needed, and others when both possibilities are correct. Have a look at those previous questions and answers.
